# AngularJS Display Blob in embed tag - Document not loaded

Tags: angularjs, pdf, blob

I already did some research about this issue, but I don't find any problems in the code. If I save the file to disk it looks fine. 
The document could not be loaded...
The javascript blob object has bytes. 
Response code is 200.

Maybe somebody finds a coding issue?

The html:

```
 <div data-ng-show="vouchercontent">
    <embed ng-src="{{vouchercontent}}" style="width:400px;height:700px;"></embed>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.vouchercontent = undefined;
$scope.generateVoucher = function() {
    var self = this;
    generateVoucherService.generateVoucher($scope.voucherdata).then(function(result) {
        var file = new Blob([result], {type: 'application/pdf' });
        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $scope.vouchercontent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
    });};
```

Angular Service:

```html
generateVoucher : function(data){         
    return $http.post('rest/generatevoucher/generate', data, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
          .then(function(response){             
              return response.data;         
           }, function (response) {             
              return $q.reject(response.data);         
           });     
}
```

Response in the service:

[image]

Response in the controller:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `result` is the response from the ajax request?

Comment: Hi Musa, I added a picture of the result content in the post...

Comment: @user1107868 did you consider [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/339)? You probably need to use a custom directive here as browsers don't dynamically react to a change in the src attribute on embed tags.

Comment: I can try this. But not sure if this is the only problem. Loading the content url in a new window has the same issue (so no usage of the embed tag)

Comment: Any luck anybody ? I am running into similar situations.